# PHP array_multisort with array_column not working

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am trying to sort multidimensional arrays by a single column. I have an array that is created in a method and returned as $GDdata. This is a snippet of my [unsorted array displayed in a table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKmZs.png).
Here I am selecting the column I want the final array to be sorted by:
`$GDcol = array_column($GDdata,0);`
I can successfully print the selected column to the screen as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ffsad.png).
Then when I try to use the selected column to sort the entire multidimensional array like this:
`$GDsorted = array_multisort($GDcol,SORT_ASC,$GDdata);`, my table that is printing out the array no longer shows up when I use my sorted array $GDsorted. This worked for me when I was using php 5.6. Now I have updated to php 7.2 (which is why the array_column is created first). I have tried taking out the SORT_ASC since it is default and I have tried combining the array_column and array_multisort into a one liner as I had it in php 5.6. I can not figure out why the array will not display after using array_multisort. I have seen posts that suggest using usort, however array_multisort is what I want to use if possible. If anyone needs more info please let me know. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve].

Comment: And post plain text, not screenshots.

Comment: Sorry @Barmar I'll remember those notes for next time, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [array_multisort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php):

> `array_multisort ( array &$array1 , mixed $array1_sort_order = SORT_ASC , mixed $array1_sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR , mixed ...$rest ) : bool`

> Returns **true** on success or **false** on failure.

`&$array1` means that it (and the other arrays) are passed by reference and are sorted in place.  So use that not the return:

```
array_multisort($GDcol, SORT_ASC, $GDdata);
print_r($GDdata);
```

And you can do it in one line and don't need `SORT_ASC`:

```
array_multisort(array_column($GDdata, 0), $GDdata);
```

Both will sort `$GDcol` and then sort `$GDdata` in the same order.

Comment: Thank you this worked! It did not click in my head that it returns a boolean instead of the sorted array. Also I read somewhere that doing it on one line would throw a warning saying "variables can only be passed by reference" but that did not pop up for me. Thank you for your time!